# How do I change the output to a string instead of it outputting a list?

Tags: python, arrays

I'm learning python and cannot get the output to be a string instead of a list. Can someone point me in the right direction please?

Here is my code:

```
def recursion(user):
    if len(user) == 0:
        return []
    else:
        return [user[0].upper()] + recursion(user[1:])
#user input

user = input("Please input your array: ")

print("Output" , ((recursion(user))))
```

[here is the output]

```
Please input your array: hi
Output ['H', 'I']
```

Process finished with exit code 0

https://i.stack.imgur.com/7diMa.png

The outcome I was trying for was `[HI]`

Comment: Can you add a sample input array to your question? How would multiple words be input for example? Separated by a comma?

Comment: What's the `#user input` comment there for?

Comment: It's completely unclear now what the desired inputs and outputs are. Is the input a string or a list? And is the desired output a string or a list? Why did you remove the assignment from the question?

Answer (score 1):

You are returning lists in your recursive function. If you want to keep it as a string, you can use:

```py
def recursion(user):
    if len(user) == 0:
        return ""
    else:
        return user[0].upper() + recursion(user[1:])
#user input

user = input("Please input your array: ")

print("Output" , ((recursion(user))))
```

Answer (score 0):

Your function is correct but you have a small misunderstanding of the assignment.

The assignment doesn't require any console `input` or output (`print`). The wording of the assignment only asks for a function. The function is the first 5 lines of your programs and it does it exactly what it should do. To test your function, simply write:

```
recursion(["Hi"])
```

The output is:

```
['HI']
```

I leave it to you to try with an array of multiple words.

The reason that `input` doesn't work as you expected is the following: `input` returns a string. That string is an array (!)* of characters But characters are still strings (with length 1). If you take the assignment literally, you don't have to worry about that special case.

*The equivalent to an "array" in other languages is called a "sequence" in Python.